# Link not clickable due to z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

So I got a wrapper with `position:relative`. Above this wrapper there is a logo with `position:fixed`. That logo is like halfway covered by the wrapper. Because I used margin to bring the wrapper a bit down, I can't click the link on the logo.
The z-index of the logo is lower than the one on the wrapper. This is meant to be like that. The logo shouldn't be in front of the wrapper.

Can I somehow make the link on the logo clickable without bringing it in front of the wrapper?

A little JS-fiddle below :)

```css
.content {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 background-color: #fff;
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
 margin: 70px auto 280px auto;
  height:1000px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

.inner-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

#logo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 50px);
  position:fixed;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="logo"></div>
</a>
<div class="inner-container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the psition of  `#logo` to `top:0px`.Add `margin-top:70px` to the `.inner-container` and set remove the top margin of `.content`

```css
.content {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 background-color: #fff;
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
 margin: 0px auto 280px auto;
    height:1000px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

.inner-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
    margin-top:70px;
}

#logo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 50px);
  position:fixed;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:black;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="alert('here')">
  <div id="logo"></div>
</a>
<div class="inner-container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace the below style case.**

```
body{
    margin-top: 70px; /* ADD THE MARGIN TOP IN THE BODY TAG */
    margin-botton: 280px; /* ADD THE MARGIN BOTTOM IN THE BODY TAG */
}
.content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    background-color: #fff;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;/* MAKE MARGIN TOP AND BOTTOM TO ZERO AND ADD THE MARGIN TOP AND BOTTOM IN THE BODY TAG */
  height:1000px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.inner-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#logo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 50px);
  position:fixed;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:black;
  top:0; /* ADD TOP AS ZERO, TO POSITION THE LOG ELEMENT FROM TOP*/
}
```